# weka EuclideanDistance

Tags: weka, euclidean-distance

I have following code to calculate the EuclideanDistance distance using weka.core.EuclideanDistance, where both two instances are all missing values, like below

Instance first are all missing values: ?,?,?,?

instance second are all missing values:?,?,?,?

```
EuclideanDistance distance = new EuclideanDistance();
distance.setInstances(test);
Instance first = test.get(0);
Instance second = test.get(1);
double d = distance.distance(first, second);
```

however, when i run the code, i got the result is 4.0, i have no idea where is this 4.0 from,can anyone tell me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried to recreate your problem, I created a ".arff" with four attributes containing only those two instances.  I also get a numerical value (1.73) but not 4.0 .  Does your test dataset contain more than the two instances?

Comment: thank you Walter, it was not 4.0 but 2.23606797749979, whatever the result is, i don't know where we can get value from all missing data?Can you tell me, how the result is calculated?

Comment: you may be able to gain some insight by looking at the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.6/weka/core/EuclideanDistance.java

Comment: Did you find an answer?  I'm interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing values in k-Nearest Neighbours algorithm usually are handled according to the following criteria:

For nominal attributes:

```
if isMissingValue(a) or isMissingValue(b), then
    distance = 1
```

For numeric attributes:

```
if isMissingValue(a) and isMissingValue(b), then
    distance = 1

if isMissingValue(a) and !isMissingValue(b), then
    distance = max(b, 1-b)

if !isMissingValue(a) and isMissingValue(b), then
    distance = max(a, 1-a)
```

You can check the implementation in the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.6/weka/core/NormalizableDistance.java#NormalizableDistance.distance%28weka.core.Instance,weka.core.Instance,double%29) (link provided by [Walter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/628499/walter)).